# java class why public static void main(String[] args) method can not access the property value of the class it is in?

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class Name{
int b = 100;
public void get(){
    System.out.println(b);
}

public int num(){
    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

}

get method can access b, num method can access b as well. why not public static void main method can access b.

Comment: static methods can access static properties only.

Answer (score 3):

Because `b` is an instance field, scoped within instances of the `Name` class.

Your `main` method is `static`, scoped within the class itself.

Declare `b` as `static` to be able to access it from the `main` method.

You'll also need to make methods `get()` and `num()` `static` to compile.

Answer (score 3):

It's an instance (non-static) field, so you need an instance to reference it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Name().b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can only access static properties.  You could either make `b` static, or you can instead instantionalize Name:

```
public class Name{
int b = 100;

public void get(){
    System.out.println(b);
}

public int num(){
    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Name(args);
}

public Name(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how the code in your answer is related to the question. I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help].